# From the Salafi understanding of Islamic law, how was participation in the 2011-2012 Egyptian elections justified?

Tags: politics, salafi

One of the well-known positions of the Salafi movement is political quietism - avoiding participation in politics, with some even holding that elections and democracy are prohibited in Islam. Yet in the [2011-2012 Egyptian elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_parliamentary_election,_2011%E2%80%9312), the al-Nour party contested the election on the Salafi platform, and finished in the second place with 27.8% popular vote, indicating high level of voter approval.

How did this party and their supporters legitimize (**using the Salafi understanding of Islamic law**) their participation, in light of the general Salafi position of avoiding politics? How mainstream is it in the Salafi movement globally to allow (1) participation in elections and (2) forming  a political party?

<sup>Note that I'm not asking the for the general ruling for participating in politics and elections, such rulings can be easily found in other sources. But I'm particularly interested in the Salafi understanding of the Islamic law given their unique position in this regard.</sup>

Comment: This is probably off-topic since it is about politics, not Islamic doctrine.

Comment: @G.Bach The question is about Salafi understanding of the Islamic law - not about the politics of it, so I believe it is on-topic. Let me clarify the question

Comment: Salafis have no consens about political participation especially in matters of Democratic elections.